# alloy formula, expressing foreach operation

Tags: formula, alloy

I am an alloy new user and I am trying to declare in a predicate that

`There is a y in Y for each x in X`

but when I write it this way :

`all x : X | all y : Y | one y`

all x : X | all y : Y | one x => one y

I have only one y for the whole X

What I expect is if there is 3 x there will be 3 y. 
I not want to use cardinality comparison because I try to model morphisms.

Can someone help me?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take user1513683's answer and have `f` be a field in a sig, as opposed to using it as a quantification variable, e.g.,

```
sig X {}
sig Y {}
one sig M {
  f: X one -> one Y
}
run {} for 4
```

As you already realized, you could avoid introducing a new sig and embed this constraint in an existential quantifier, e.g.,

```
run {
  some f: X one -> one Y | 1=1
} for 4
```

The reason why you can here use an existential quantifier over a binary relation is the underlying constraint solving mechanism.  If the goal is to find just one instance of a binary relation (existential quantification) for which the quantifier's body holds true, that's much easier than asking whether the body holds true for all possible instances of a binary relation (universal quantification). For the former case, the quantifier can be skolemized, i.e., replaced with a number of free variables, and then the solver is asked to find **any** solution (a set of values for those variables) such that the body holds; that process is simply not possible when the goal is to check the body for **all** possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

## Y=#X says that there are the same number of Ys as Xs.

Or do you mean #X=<#Y ? There is a y in Y for each x in X, and possibly some spare Ys.

Or do you need a name for the connection?  In which case, introduce

f : X one->one Y // exactly one-one
or
f : X lone->one Y // every X has exactly one Y, but a Y has at most one X

in an appropriate signature.

Comment: Thaks for the help.

I tried tour second approach by specifying  a predicate like this 

"all f : X one -> one Y "


but the solver told me that it requires higher-order quantification that could not be skolemized.

Then I tried with the some quantifier :
"some f : X one -> one Y "
and it worked.

I understand the difference between the some and all quantifiers but I cannot understand the semantic difference in the expression.
could you explain me why one quantifier is skolemizable and the other not? 
thanks